# Why is "insert "SimpleName" to complete ClassType" showing up?

Tags: java

The problem shows up when I call the 2nd initialization method, but not the first.

I've looked for 30 minutes and couldn't find anything to fix the error.

```java
final public class Matrix{
    private final int M, N;//rows and columns
    public final double[][] data;
    public Matrix(int M, int N) {
        this.M = M;
        this.N = N;
        data = new double[M][N];
    }
    public Matrix(double[][] data) {
        M = data.length;
        N = data[0].length;
        this.data = new double[M][N];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.M; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.N; j++) {
                this.data[i][j] = data[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    private Matrix(Matrix A) {this(A.data); } // copy matrix
}
```

```java
private Matrix m1;
m1 = new @Matrix({{1.0,2.0},{1.0,2.0}});
```

```java
double[][] d;
d = new double[m1.data.length][m1.data[0].length];
for(int i = 0; i < m1.data.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < m1.data[0].length; j++) {
        d[i][j] = m1.data[i][j];
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(d));
```

it's supposed to print the matrix as an array but the errors:

```
Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete ClassType
Syntax error, insert "( )" to complete Expression
```

shows up

Comment: What's the stack trace of the error?

Comment: A quick search for your error brings up many instances where code was written in the wrong section. Where are the two last code snippets written (`private Matrix m1` through `System.out.println...`), in the `main` method or floating around the class or file?

Answer (score 3):

For one,

```
m1 = new @Matrix({{1.0,2.0},{1.0,2.0}});
```

should be:

```
m1 = new Matrix(new double[][]{{1.0,2.0},{1.0,2.0}});
```

This place is probably what is causing you to see the stack trace you're seeing, as the format for `ClassType` (defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-ClassType)) can be led by an Annotation. An annotation (defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-NormalAnnotation)) may be led by an `@` symbol, so I presume that this is what the compiler was complaining about - starting the ClassType but not finishing it properly.
For another,

```
final public class Matrix{
```

should probably (not *necessary* for correctness, but stylistically consistent) be:

```
public final class Matrix{
```

Make sure that

```
private Matrix m1;
```

is declared as a field. If it's a local variable, take the `private` modifier away.

After making these changes, I get the output:

> > java Main
>   [[1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0]]

You can view my test code [here](https://repl.it/repls/CooperativeOtherSubversion).